# moment tz convert string

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

This should be simple, but I spent hours going over documentation and still got nothing.
I have this string:

```
var time = "2018-09-29 23:50:21"
```

This time is in UTC, even though it does not say so, I know it is.

I want to convert it to PST (America/Los_Angeles) with .tz

I tried:

```
moment(time).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format(MomentDefaults.DateTime);
```

I get **"Sep 29, 2018, 23:50"**

I tried MANY different combination that failed in different ways.

I want to be able to print **"Sep 29, 2018, 16:50"** which is `time` in utc converted to pst.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your `time` string to be an actual valid ISO UTC string since you are sure it is?

```js
var time = "2018-09-29T23:50:21.000Z"

console.log(moment(time).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format())  //16:50
console.log(moment(time).tz('America/New_York').format())     //19:50
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you have the data for the timezones loaded etc as [per the docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/):

> In Node.js, all the data is preloaded. No additional code is needed
> for loading data.
>
> When using Moment Timezone in the browser, you will need to load the
> data as well as the library.